# Force quit shortcut?

Tags: macbook-pro

go to the "" then go down to "Force Quit..." and then there are three symbols after that meaning the shortcut keys, what does the last one mean? I've honestly tried to find it for a year!

Comment: https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193/

Answer (score 3):

The circle with the diagonal arrow is the Escape key.

⎋ is entered as the HTML entity `&#9099;`

[Source](https://www.danrodney.com/mac/).

[image]